# import.meta.url breaking after packing

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, rollup, packing

My workspace looks like this:

```
├─dist
│ └─index.mjs
└─src
  └─utils
     └─index.ts
```

I use `import.meta.url` in `/src/utils/index.ts` like this:

```js
const __path_src_root = path.resolve(
  path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)),
  '../',
);
const __path_cache = path.resolve(
  __path_src_root,
  '../node_modules/.cache/@setup',
);
```

After packaging, `import.meta.url` will change due to directory changes, breaking the `__path_cache`. It changes from `/path/to/cli/node_modules/.cache/@setup` to `/path/to/node_modules/.cache/@setup`.

Is there a way to resolve this?

I don't want to use env var like `process.env.prod ? ... : ...`

By the way, I use `rollup` to pack my code and tried to find plugin to solve it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to keep a similar directory structure for our input and output?

Comment: @Evert It's a good solution. It may be possible to change `/src/utils/index.ts` to `/src/utils.ts`, but how to name `/src/utils` folder? The directory structure needs to be clear, which confuses me a bit...